# Add static values to GridViewComboBoxColumn WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, radgridview

I'm using `WPF` application in which i have to add static values to `GridViewComboboxColumn` in a `RadGridView`.

I need something like,

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Item" 
DataMemberBinding="{Binding SeriesItem, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="*"> 
Code here...
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: You can do that, though it would be XAML, not what I call 'code', but to each his markup.

Comment: To get you started, look on telerik http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/columns/celltemplate-and-celledittemplate   Also their demo you can download has examples.